# With XHTML namespaces, should each attribute have a namespace too?

Tags: xml, xhtml

When extending XHTML for a very simple CMS, I'm wondering if I should use

```
<cms:include document="foo/bar" />
```

or

```
<cms:include cms:document="foo/bar" />
```

Given a document declared as follows:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:cms="http://spongegroup.com/ns/cms">
```

(basically the idea is to make a simple parser that white-lists a few XHTML tags, and adds a couple of my own).

Is the cms: prefix needed on attributes of an element that is already in the cms: namespace?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not need the `cms:` prefix on the attributes of `cms:` elements, because the meaning of these attributes is determined by the element they belong to.

See the [XML namespace recommendation](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml-names/#defaulting): “the interpretation of unprefixed attributes is determined by the element on which they appear”.

Technically speaking however, unprefixed attributes belong to the null namespace.

*Answer edited on 2011-06-06 to correct a misleading sentence. Thanks to the commenters.*

Comment: "By default, the XML attributes of a given element belong to this element's namespace". That's either wrong or misleading. Unprefixed attributes are always in the *null namespace*, not the XML namespace of the element to which they belong. What the quote you give means is that the attribute is sufficiently *qualified* by the element to which it belongs, not that it adopts the element's namespace. You are correct that the attribute does not need to have a prefix or namespace assigned to it.

Comment: Thanks guys... seems like a subtle distinction to me, but it's good that I don't need the ns: prefix on every attribute.

Comment: Downvote as the answer is simply wrong - please rephrase. Alochi is correct; attributes are in the null namespace by default. Not being aware of this will cause serious problems when trying to use things like XSLT.

Comment: I partially rephrased the answer to correct the misleading sentence.

Comment: Ok. I still wouldn't use the phrase "sufficiently qualified" as it will be confused with "qualified name" when what you really mean is "disambiguated" or something similar.